# Automatically remove checkboxes when a list is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to keep track of the trainings completed for my team, I'm using query function and checkboxes at the moment. However, the raw data gets refreshed every week and if any person leaves the team, his/her name will be automatically removed from the removed from the list, as I'm using query function the names will be updated in my table too however, the checkboxes will remain checked based on the order of previous list.

What can I do to remove the checkboxes that are updated for a specific person?

For example: lets say there was person 7 trained only for group 2 and after days he has left the job,

the data in raw sheet was refreshed after a week and person 7 was removed from the list. Due to this my table in Summary sheet gets updated and the person 8 moves up to the top where I had checked Group 2 for person 7. However, Person 8 was trained for Group 2 and Group 3 and all the names after person 6 now shows incorrect data

what can I do to automatically remove the checkboxes that was updated for a specific person?

Please help

Please check the example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1slzGZ1G9t5yOAenwct5mHjwnQf_YKLV0iBMMwXBIReg/edit#gid=1603256116

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removecheckboxes

Answer (score 2):

You are describing how formula results get misaligned with manually entered data. Lance has given a thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases.

In this instance, the easiest solution would probably be to insert the checkbox columns next to the 'Raw' table instead of adding it to the 'Summary' table.

In the event the 'Raw' tab contains lots of data, and that makes managing the checkboxes cumbersome, you can use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit the sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.